# Read messages from Kafka topic between a range of offsets

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am looking for a way to consume some set of messages from my Kafka topic with specific offset range (assume my partition has offset from 200 - 300, I want to consume the messages from offset 250-270).

I am using below code where I can specify the initial offset, but it would consume all the messages from 250 to till end. Is there any way/attributes available to set the end offset to consume the messages till that point.

```
    @KafkaListener(id = "KafkaListener",
        topics = "${kafka.topic.name}", 
        containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory", 
        errorHandler = "${kafka.error.handler}",
        topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(topic = "${kafka.topic.name}",
        partitionOffsets = {
                @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "250"), 
                @PartitionOffset(partition = "1", initialOffset = "250")
        }))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`seek()`](http://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,%20long)) in order to force the consumer to start consuming from a specific *offset* and then `poll()` until you reach the target end offset.

> `public void seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset)`
>
> Overrides the fetch offsets that the consumer will use on the next `poll(timeout)`. If this API is invoked for the
>   same partition more than once, the latest offset will be used on the
>   next `poll()`. Note that you may lose data if this API is arbitrarily
>   used in the middle of consumption, to reset the fetch offsets

---

For example, let's assume you want to start from offset `200`:

```
TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("myTopic", 0);
Long startOffset = 200L
Long endOffset = 300L

List<TopicPartition> topics = Arrays.asList(tp);
consumer.assign(topics);
consumer.seek(topicPartition, startOffset);
```

now you just need to keep `poll()`ing until `endOffset` is reached:

```
boolean run = true;
while (run) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

        // Do whatever you want to do with `record`

        // Check if end offset has been reached
        if (record.offset() == endOffset) {
            run = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);

boolean keepOnReading = true;

// offset to read the data from.
long offsetToReadFrom = 250L; 

// seek is mostly used to replay data or fetch a specific message
// seek
kafkaConsumer.seek(partitionToReadFrom, offsetToReadFrom);

while(keepOnReading) {
   ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));

   for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
      numberOfMessagesRead ++;
      logger.info("Key: "+record.key() + ", Value: " + record.value());
      logger.info("Partition: " + record.partition() + ", Offset: " + record.offset());

      if(record.offset() == 270L) {
        keepOnReading = false;
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

I hope this helps you !!